# Irreducible polynomial over field $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

How to show that $f(x)= x^4 + 2x^2 + x −1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$?

If its degree where odd, then obviously it must be reducible over $\mathbb{R}$, but here degree is even. I also do know its reducible over field with three elements. It's  irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So by $p$-modulo test  it's irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. But I am getting annoyed when it comes to $\mathbb{R}$. Is there any short method to cope such problem in bond of times like within $1$ or $2$ minutes span of time.

Comment: What is your $R$? Is it the field of real numbers $\mathbb R$? In that case the polynomial cannot be irreducible over $\mathbb R$ as it has a root in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: All polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree greater than 2 are reducible (Hint: Think of solutions over $\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: It is not irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_2$. Modulo two $1$ is a root, and $x-1$ a factor. Also three is odd, so I don't understand your second and third sentences at all.

Comment: Sorry  I edited the question and discarded some part.

Comment: Actually question was $f(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + x − 1$

Comment: It's still a polynomial of degree $3$ and as @AnotherJohnDoe said, it must be reducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: @AotherJohnDoes thanks..... Is it a result to mug up........

Comment: @take008 I owe my apologies..... it's of degree 4 and corrected.

Comment: It's still a polynomial of degree $>2$, so it must be reducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: Here are more hints for how to prove the proposition https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275953/all-polynomials-in-bbb-r-can-be-factored-as-a-product-of-polynomials-over-b?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is solved if we just consider the comment of the user AnotherJohnDoe as above. But there is a another simple view to deal with it. Now let $f(x):=x^{4}+2x^{2}+x-1$ and hence this is a real-valued continuous function on the interval $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=3.$ Thus, we see on account of $0$ is between $-1$ and $3$, one has that $f(\eta)=0$ for some $\eta\in(0,1),$ where we used the Intermediate value theorem to conclude. So $f$ has a factor $(x-\eta)$ with $\eta\in(0,1).$

Comment: Sorry sir don't know I posted the wrong question and asking something else. Now I edited and now it's fine.  It's all due to hectic schedule.

Comment: @TheIotaa even if the post edited, this method still works. By the way, I edited the function $f.$